# error sas export to csv

Tags: csv, sas, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export a large SAS file to csv. I used

```
proc export data=study1
    outfile='C:\Users\me\Documents\excel File\study1.csv'
    dbms=csv;
run;
```

I get the error:

**ERROR: Physical file does not exist, C:\Users\Ingrid\Documents\excel File\study1.csv.**

Why is it showing an error? I thought the outfile is arbitrary and will create a study1.csv when the proc is executed?

I also tried doing file>export data and got a csv file. bu when I tried to open it it says it's not actually a csv file, but an SYLK file.

I hope I can make the proc export work.

Thanks all

Comment: check and make sure the path you are using exists.

Comment: Yep.  That error indicates that the folder you are referencing doesn't exist.  Does "excel file" directory exist?

Comment: Also, the SYLK file issue is irrelevant; it's really making a CSV file.  Excel just gets confused.  You likely have "ID" at the start of your file; see [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626).

Answer (score 1):

If the first record of your CSV file is “ID”, Excel will attempt to intepret the file as SYLK. Changing “ID” to anything else (including “Id” or “id”) fixes the issue.